# jquery optimization in case of array comparison

Tags: jquery

> I want the below piece of code to be optimized.

- Inputs : jsonData is a JSON containing all the avaya skills
- sitePbx is a array containing the pbxs of a particular site

> Considerations : The number of lines of code should be less as
>   compared to above code

- The code should be generic in a way so that in

> future if a new PBX is added, no more if-else is required
>
> Number of
>   comparisons should be less so that performance is optimized

Comment: The amount of damage that copy and paste concept made to good programming is amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pbxNames = {"Elk Grove": "ElkGrove"};
var container = $('#' + attributeTableId + portletId);

$.each(jsonData, function(i, json) {
    var addPbx = true;
    $.each(sitePbx, function(j, pbx) {
        if (json[pbxNames[pbx] || pbx] == 'null') {
            addPbx = false;
        }
    });
    if (addPbx) {
        container.append('<option value="' +
                         json.id +
                         '">' +
                         json.name +
                         '</option>');
    }
});
```

The idea is: instead of checking for `Pbx`s individually just loop over the elements of `sitePbx` and check if the associated tag is present in the JSON node.

The `pbxNames` map is present because of `Elk Grove` (in other cases the tag is the same as the name). Adding a new PBX should just be automatic, except if the name requires a translation to the tag in `pbxNames`.

Removing the spaces could be used instead of a map, but it's also less general.

I highly doubt this code can be a problem for performance but looking up the container only once instead that once per `jsonData` element should be better.

If `jsonData` is really really huge and only very few options are going to be added then some metaprogramming could be reasonable (i.e. generating the unrolled function on the fly using `eval`).